# scipy.pdist() returns NaN values

Tags: python, nan, correlation, pearson-correlation, pdist

I'm trying to cluster time series. The intra-cluster elements have same shapes but different scales. Therefore, I would like to use a correlation measure as metric for clustering. I'm trying correlation or pearson coefficient distance (any suggestion or alternative is welcome).
However, the following code returns error when I run Z = linkage(dist) because there are some NaN values in dist. There are not NaN values in time_series, this is confirmed by

```
np.any(isnan(time_series))
```

which returns False

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

dist = pdist(time_series, metric='correlation') 
Z = linkage(dist)
fig = plt.figure()
dn = dendrogram(Z)
plt.show()
```

As alternative, I will use pearson distance

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

def pearson_distance(a,b):
    return 1 - pearsonr(a,b)[0]

dist = pdist(time_series, pearson_distance)`
```

but this generates some runtime warnings and takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scipy.pdist(time_series, metric='correlation')
```

If you take a look at the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html), the `correlation` options divides by the difference. So it could be that you have two timestamps that are the same, and dividing `zero` by `zero` gives us `NaN`.

Comment: Ok,i verified that when one of the two sequences has the Same values for all the timesteps the coefficient is nan. How should i handle this case?

Comment: This really depends on your case. You could either ignore and delete these entries, this would be the case if they have no physical/whatsoever meaning. Or you could set them to zero, but I'm not sure about the implications regarding the correlation interpretation. Kind of your choice.

Comment: I need to cluster these series, therefore I need a metric to say if  two series a and b are similar (in shape, regardless the scale) or not.

Comment: then just delete these values. Having the same value for all timesteps gives you a constant over time, so basically no temporal information. An `if` condition that deletes the values should do it in that case.
(consider marking the question as answered in that case...)

Comment: what if I add an epsilon to the last value of any constant series? so that this very little perturbation will cause variance different than zero

Comment: you will change the correlation of your timeseries. Thats again your choice to make. I don't have enough information about your problem to see the impact of that variation.